# verification of the equality of immutable arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jasmine, jestjs

I have two immutable arrays. One is ordinary ([1,2,3,4]), the other is multiplied by two ([2,4,6,8]).
How in the test to equalize each value of the first array with the value of the second I use the iteration? That 1 is 2, and 2 is 4 and so on.
I think this can be done with a for loop, but I do not know how to write this in practice.

```
import { List, Set } from "immutable"

export function mass() {
  let standardArray = List([1,2,3,4]);
  let mutatedArray = standardArray.map(x => x * 2);
  return mutatedArray;
};
```

test code
(I do not know how to proceed)

```
import { List, Set, isImmutable, Record, Map } from "immutable"
import { mass } from "./sum";

test('Array Multiplication Test', () => {
  let standardArray = List([1,2,3,4]);
  let mutatedArray = standardArray.map(x => x * 2);
  expect(standardArray).not.toEqual(mutatedArray);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more about **How in the test to equalize each value of the first array with the value of the second I use the iteration? That 1 is 2, and 2 is 3 and so on**

Comment: Specifically on **and 2 is 3** ?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to compare two arrays to check if they're not the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: There are two arrays and you need to compare them. The test should check that all values of the first array correspond to the whole value of the second array multiplied by 2.

Comment: then 2 should be 4 right? why 3?

Comment: I made a mistake
1 is 2
2 is 4
3 is 6
and so on

Comment: If this is a test case for you code and not just a coding exercise, it seems pretty pointless to test that multiplication works unless you have statically defined data, as you're still using `*` to create and test the data

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of a flag. Take a flag variable and set it to any value, loop through the array and if any value does not meet expectations, change the flag variable.
In the end, check the value of flag variable. If it is the same as set initially then they are same otherwise the arrays are different.

```js
import { List, Set, isImmutable, Record, Map } from "immutable"
import { mass } from "./sum";

test('Array Multiplication Test', () => {
  let standardArray = List([1,2,3,4]);
  let mutatedArray = standardArray.map(x => x * 2);
  let flag = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < standardArray.length; i++) {
    if (standardArray[i] * 2 != mutatedArray[i]) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  expect(flag).toEqual(false);
});
```

Comment: that in the loop was expect and every time checked the value, if 1 is equal to 2 is true, and 2 is not equal to 4, then an error occurred

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```js
let testArr1 = [1,2,3,4]
let testArr2 = [2,4,6,8]
let testArr3 = [2,6,6,8]

function doesMatchCriteria(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  return arr1.every((e, i) => ((e*2) === arr2[i]));
  return true;
}
console.log(doesMatchCriteria(testArr1, testArr2));  // true
console.log(doesMatchCriteria(testArr1, testArr3));  // false
```

So, your `test` function could be something like this:

```
test('Array Multiplication Test', () => {
  let testArr1 = [1,2,3,4]
  let testArr2 = [2,4,6,8]
  expect(doesMatchCriteria(testArr1, testArr2)).toBe(true);
});
```

Don't forget to define `doesMatchCriteria` function in the same file.

Comment: I was thinking the same but **1 is 2 and 2 is 3** got me like **.....**

Comment: almost true, but how to implement it in the form of a test jest

Comment: you need to expect in the loop and check the value every time, if 1 is equal to 2, and 2 is not equal to 4, then you get an error

Comment: @deniz that is exactly what the function `doesMatchCriteria` does

Comment: so the lambda multiplication function itself is already written.
it remains to write a loop in the test.
why should I re-write the function?

Comment: It's totally up to you, how you want to implement this :)